# How to properly apply routes inside another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, middleware

I'm fairly new to express js and I want to know how to use router. I created a file named categories.js inside routes directory with this code.

categories.js code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/categories', function(req, res) {
    res.send('this is the category');
});

module.exports = router;
```

inside the app.js i have this code:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var categories = require('./routes/categories');

var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hjs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/categories', categories);


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

I have tried understand what is wrong but i can't see to figure out. thanks in advance.

This is the error im getting

Not Found

404

I will like to add inside the routes directory i have a index.js file and this one works.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I think my application is not reading the categories.js file, because when I put the category.js code inside index.js it works. but it doesn't work if i put it in a separate file in my case category.js.

Comment: What errors are you seeing?

Comment: Can you be more specific? So you started your app (or did you?) `node app`. And then went to specified port `http://localhost:3000/`, or whatever. Then what happened? Was there an error? What specifically occurred to make you believe it was wrong?

Comment: What was the URL that gave you 404? And was there an error in the command console?

Comment: I go to http://localhost:3000/categories in the browser and I get that respond back from the browser. I started the app using nodemon and the applicaiton works with I go to http://localhost:3000/

Comment: Are you running `node app` command from the command line? Or are you using something like WebStorm? And if so, do you see any errors in the command line or your IDE console?

Comment: im using webStorm and the command line give me no error.

Comment: so you are running it from command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got your categories route hooked up wrong, your categories are mapped to `/categories/categories` in your code. To fix it, try this in your app.js:

```
app.use('/', categories);
```

If you don't want to prefix, you can also simply do this:

```
app.use(categories);
```